# Why does Fraction use __new__ instead of __init__?

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to make a new immutable type, similar to the built-in `Fraction` but not derived from it.  The Fraction class [is created like this](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/fractions.py):

```
# We're immutable, so use __new__ not __init__
def __new__(cls, numerator=0, denominator=None):
    ...
    self = super(Fraction, cls).__new__(cls)
    self._numerator = ...
    self._denominator = ...
    return self
```

but I don't see how this is any different from

```
def __init__(self, numerator=0, denominator=None):
    ...
    self._numerator = ...
    self._denominator = ...
```

<s>Creating 2 `Fraction` objects with the same value does not create 2 labels pointing to the same object/memory location</s>   (Actually it was pointed out in the comments that it is not common for types to do this.)

Despite the source code comment, they aren't actually immutable:

```
f1 = Fraction(5)

f2 = Fraction(5)

id(f1), id(f2)
Out[35]: (276745136, 276745616)

f1._numerator = 6

f1
Out[41]: Fraction(6, 1)

f2
Out[42]: Fraction(5, 1)

id(f1)
Out[59]: 276745136
```

So what's the point of doing it this way?

The docs say

> `__new__()` is intended mainly to allow subclasses of immutable types (like int, str, or tuple) to customize instance creation. It is also
>   commonly overridden in custom metaclasses in order to customize class
>   creation.

So if I'm not subclassing a built in type, but I'm making an immutable type from scratch (subclass of `object`), do I still need to use it?

Comment: Built-in objects with the same value aren't always the same instance. Small integers are special case. If you try the above test with `int(1000)` instead of `int(5)` you'll see that `i1 is i2` is false.

Comment: It is possible to make `new` return an existing object instead of creating a new one (if that's what you want). That way if you try and construct it twice you'll get the same object with the same id. That's not necessarily beneficial, and most built in classes do not do that.

Comment: @khelwood Ok I thought they all did that.  What is beneficial or not beneficial about doing that?  I would expect there to be no benefits to creating multiple identical equivalent objects with the same immutable value.  Don't they just waste memory and memory access time?

Comment: @endolith Because in order to do that you have to keep hold of references to all the objects you might want to return. Suppose you keep track of every object you instantiate in case you need to instantiate an identical one - then none of those can be garbage collected, and every new instantiation takes longer because you have to search through your cache to see if it contains the one you want.

Comment: @khelwood Oh I see, so that's why built in int type does that for small common ints but not for large uncommon ones.

Answer (score 5):

If you are making a truly immutable type, you should use `__new__`, because the **self** object passed into `__init__` would logically be immutable already, so it would be too late to assign the values to its members.  This is more drastic for those writing subclasses, because adding members would be forbidden.

Since immutability is actually not an intrinsic property, but a trick, generally enforced by hooking `__setattr__`, people do write immutable types that initialize with `__init__` and then *make* themselves immutable by setting some member that then makes setting other members impossible.  But the logic in such situations can become quite tortuous, and `__setattr__` can become riddled with extra rules.

It makes more sense to have some kind of mutable type, and inherit the immutable type from it with the version of `__setattr__` that just **raises**'s an exception included in the subclass.  This makes the logic of using `__new__` obvious.  Since it can make the mutable superclass and modify it, but then return it as the inherited type, it is less confusing.

If **Fraction** intended to be immutable, the implementers either missed that step, or thought better of it later and forgot to remove their comment.

```
>>> class Pair(object):
...     def __init__(self, key, value):
...         self.key = key
...         self.value = value
...
>>> class ImPair(Pair):
...     def __new__(cls, key, value):
...         self = Pair(key, value)
...         self.__class__ = cls
...     def __setattr__(self, name, value):
...         raise AttributeError(name)
...    
>>> x = Pair(2,3)
>>> x.key
2
>>> x.key = 9
>>> x.key
9
>>> x = ImPair(2,3)
>>> x.key
2
>>> x.key = 9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __setattr__
AttributeError: key
>>>
```

Comment: `Fraction` was written that way as the prototype -- if it is ever implemented in `C` it will be immutable without any tricks.

Comment: It seems un-Pythonic to write something so straightforward outside the language.  Explicit is better than implicit...

Comment: There is nothing implicit about writing a data type in `C`, or any of the other implementation languages for Python.  The biggest reason to do so is probably performance (the pure Python version can be extremely slow).

Comment: Yes there is.  If not everyone can read the implementation, then for those people, the details below the documentation description are implicit.  English never explains everything.  They must simply trust it.  If they can read the code, their understanding is that much more explicit.

Comment: And the 'c' implementation will still have a function mapped to __setattr__.  How that is implemented is what will make the thing mutable or immutable.  So your initial comment makes no sense to me.  There  is not some more explicit way of defining something immutable to the Python interpreter, whatever language you write it in.

Comment: I did not mean tricks are bad.  They are good when they add unexpected elegance and power.  Separate implementation of immutability as a special case at the compiler level, as it is handled in most languages, would make Python either redundant, or less powerful.

Comment: @JonJayObermark don't you need to `return self` in `ImPair.__new__()`? My understanding is that `__new__()` needs to return a constructed object right?